# Translate text of email footer(Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email-translation

I need to translate the text `<a href="">Share the love !</a>`. I have added the text in theme's translate.csv file like this `"Share the love !","Partagez votre Passion !"`, but the text not translated in footer(`app/locale/en_US/template/email/html/footer.html`).I have translated the text by creating footer template for each store view. Is any other way there to translate the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to email template then you can translate it by adding translation in transactional emails.

Go to System->Transactional Emails then click "Add New Template" at the top right then choose the footer template and language then modify according to your style and then save it.

[image]

Or if it is in the template like in footer.phtml the you should wrap it with `"$this->__('translatable text')"` or in your case `<?php echo $this->__('Share the love !'); ?>` and your translation will work from that translate.csv file.

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Magento CSV translations files in order to translate only `dynamic` content in your emails. For example, `order_new.html` which is the order confirmation email template contains (for every language)  `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}`, which is pointing to the `items.phtml` (and retrieving all the order items in your email). The text here is translated based on the CSV files using the `__` function. 
However, in your case, it's a `static`text which needs to be translated so the CSV approach will not help you. By copying the `footer.html` in every corresponding `locale` and translating it (like you actually did), is the correct approach here.

I hope it helps!